# Relative Path Not Working with Base URL in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, base-url

Here's the setup:
I'm using the latest version of IE11 (11.0.9600.18952IS I just updated today). I have a .NET application using AngularJs 1.5. In my main view, I set the base:

```
<%-- resolves to "/" --%>
<base href="<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>" />
```

My image is on this relative path: DesktopModules/Module/Images/Image.png. This works in Chrome but not IE. I'm getting a "404 Not Found" error. I looked at the path that gets generated in my HTML and I see that a part of my sites URL has been added and that is breaking the path:

```
**en-us/Resources**/DesktopModules/Module/Images/Image.png
```

After an hour of researching with no results I was unable to fix this issue.

Comment: Having the same issue. Also haven't found a cause yet. For us, the link only doesn't work when it is actually clicked on. If we right click and then select "Open link" or "Open link in new tab" or "Copy", the URL is rendered correctly. Only when we left click on the link on the page does the issue arise. It is almost certainly an IE bug.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to add "/" to the front of my relative path. I gave up on researching a fix and just played with the file path and this was it. Seems like such a simple fix. Somebody must have encountered this before. Hope this helps someone.

I changed this: DesktopModules/Module/Images/Image.png

To this: /DesktopModules/Module/Images/Image.png